# Is Eclipse ADT officially abandoned?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, adt, eclipse-adt

Google is no longer supporting the ADT plugin, and it is actively encouraging developers to migrate to Android Studio. The official announcement about the ADT Plugin being DEPRECATED was posted on 26 June 2015 at https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html. It is also clearly stated at https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html.

Is the Eclipse Foundation still supporting and encouraging Developers to use Eclipse ADT for Android development, or did even the Eclipse Foundation give up and abandon Eclipse ADT? I am wondering if Android Studio and Eclipse ADT are still competitors, or if Eclipse ADT was defeated and they just gave up. It is obvious that Google wants everyone to use Android Studio, but what is the position of the Eclipse Foundation about that?

Comment: Eclipse ADT is no longer supported at all.

Comment: "We are ending development and official support for the Android Developer Tools (ADT) in Eclipse at the end of the year" (https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html). By "We" they mean the Google/Android team. By "end of the year" they mean end of 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no competition at-all. Android Studio is de-facto industry standard now.

Eclipse ADT was built and maintained by Google and not by eclipse foundation. Android Studio is far better IDE then Eclipse ADT ever was. Google has long abandoned ADT for good and so did the industry.

Comment: "Eclipse ADT was built and maintained by Google". That explains everything. I thought it was built and maintained by the Eclipse Foundation or another organization external to Google.

Answer (score 2):

The Eclipse Foundation is working on [Andmore](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.andmore):

> The purpose of Eclipse Andmore is to provide Android Eclipse tooling without having to go through multiple steps.
>
> The technology development involves integrating and refactoring the Google ADT plugins as necessary to work with the project. Similarly, the former MOTODEV plugins have components that can be integrated into the project.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, since late 2015.

> we are ending development and official support for the Android Developer Tools (ADT) in Eclipse at the end of the year.

[Link to source](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html)